# Как сделать проверку условия в еще одном условии

Tags: python, if

Подскажите какой оператор нужно использовать в Питоне для выполнения условия при верном выполнении предыдущего условия?
Имеем набор из трех животных. Если пользователь вводит какое-либо животное, нужно предложить ему угадать его цвет.

```
animal1= "Слон"
animal2="Пчела"
animal3="Аист"

while True:
user_animal = input("Введи одно из трех животных: Слон, Пчела, Аист")
if user_animal == animal1:
    guess_color = input("Угадай цвет")
    while guess_color != "синий":
        print("Не верно")
        guess_color = input("Угадай цвет")
    if guess_color == "синий":
        print("Верно")
        break
elif user_animal == animal2:
    guess_color = input("Угадай цвет")
    while guess_color != "желтый":
        print("Не верно")
        guess_color = input("Угадай цвет")
    if guess_color == "желтый":
        print("Верно")
        break
elif user_animal == animal3:
    guess_color = input("Угадай цвет")
    while guess_color != "белый":
        print("Не верно")
        guess_color = input("Угадай цвет")
    if guess_color == "белый":
        print("Верно")
        break
else:
    print("Данного животного нет.")
```

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос, но смею предположить, что вы имеете ввиду продолжение ветвления: `elif user_animal == "animal2":`

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что вы имеете в в виду

Comment: Нам надо чтоб при совпадении условия с названием животного выпадало следующее условие на проверку его цвета

Comment: Мы пытались использовать вложенный оператор if в операторе if, но питон выдает ошибку. Как мы видим ситуацию: if user_animal == animal1 guess_color = input("Угадай цвет") if guess_color =="синий"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы пишите, что и для цвета вопрос должен быть закольцован, то чтобы избежать раздувания листинга, необходимо исключать дублирование кода.

```
guess_matrix = {'Слон':['Серый'], 'Пчела':['Желтый','Черный'], 'Аист':['Белый','Черный']}

animals = guess_matrix.keys()
while True:
    user_animal = input("Введи одно из трех животных: Слон, Пчела, Аист")
    if user_animal in animals:
        colors = guess_matrix[user_animal]
        while True:
            guess_color = input("Угадай цвет")
            if guess_color in colors:
                pass
                break
            else:
                print("Для данного животного это не верный цвет.")
        break
    else: 
        print("Данного животного нет.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я смог понять ваше задание - вот ответ. Не забывайте про табуляцию после условий и циклов!

```
...
while True:
    user_animal = input("Введи одно из трех животных: Слон, Пчела, Аист")
    if user_animal == animal1:
        guess_color = input("Угадай цвет")
        if guess_color == <нужный цвет>:
            <блок кода>
            break
        if guess_color != <нужный цвет>:
            <блок кода>
    elif user_animal == animal2:
        guess_color = input("Угадай цвет")
        if guess_color == <нужный цвет>:
            <блок кода>
            break
        if guess_color != <нужный цвет>:
            <блок кода>
    elif user_animal == animal3:
        guess_color = input("Угадай цвет")
        if guess_color == <нужный цвет>:
            <блок кода>
            break
        if guess_color != <нужный цвет>:
            <блок кода>
    else: 
        print("Данного животного нет.")
```

Comment: используйте `if user_animal in []` - во избежание дублирования кода

Comment: Да, вы все правильно поняли. Но как быть в случае неверного ответа пользователем? Что нужно прописать чтобы снова задался вопрос про животное или цвет в зависимости от того что именно пользователь ввел неверно

Comment: Как мне кажется, если человек спрашивает базовые вещи, не стоит ему усложнять задачу.

Comment: Я обновил ответ. Теперь мы взяли в бесконечный цикл логику программы, и при не верном ответе, программа будет спрашивать заново, но если ответ будет верным, сработает команда break и цикл завершится. Надеюсь, я помог вам(если это так, поставьте галочку слева, что ответ Вас устраивает).

Comment: Да, очень помогли. Но если пользователь вводит неверный цвет, снова использовать оператор if? Как закольцевать вопрос про цвет пока не получим верный ответ? Сейчас пытались - ничего не получилось, pycharm подсвечивает оранжевым.

Comment: Я обновил ответ!

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Они очень помогли, но мы сами дописали код что бы добиться именно того результата которого хотели. Обновили первый пост